# What do "current", "worse" and "threshold" reallocated sectors mean in harddrive SMART info?

Tags: hard-drive, smart

CrystalDiskInfo reports the following warning:

```
Number of reallocated sectors:
Current: 96
Worse: 96
Threshold: 10
Raw value: 00000000000A
```

But I have no idea how to read these numbers. What do the current/worse values mean in particular, and what is the threshold?

**Edit**

Please see below the details of the drive:

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] and provide the full smart information and the make/model of the drive.

Comment: @DavidPostill, I've now uploaded a picture with the full details of the drive and SMART data.

Comment: Your drive *could* fail at any moment or it could last a few more months it is impossible to tell. You should perform a backup now. Keep an eye on this value - if it keeps on increasing it means failure is imminent.

Comment: Sorry which value should I keep an eye on? Is that the raw value that changes over time?

Comment: Raw and Actual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What do the current/worse values mean in particular, and what is the threshold?

> [image]

Source [S.M.A.R.T. Atttribute](http://crystalmark.info/software/CrystalDiskInfo/manual-en/SmartInfo.html)

Explanation:

> - Attributes describes the measured value of hard drive controller operations.
> - The values of an attribute are: current, worst, threshold and raw.
> - Values are normalized to a vendor specific scale. Scales could be ranged up to 100, 200 or 253.
> - Often higher values are better than lower values.
> - The threshold marks the value at which the hard drive could fail.
> - The worst value is the baddest value seen for this drive at this attribute.
> - The raw value is a vendor coded count that give, after decoding, the normal values like current, worst and threshold.

Source [S.M.A.R.T Value Interpretation](http://www.easis.com/smart-value-interpretation.html)

---

#### Further Reading

- [Predict if Hard Disk Failure is Imminent with CrystalDiskInfo](https://www.pcsteps.com/2530-predict-hard-disk-failure-crystal-disk-info/#How_CrystalDiskInfo_predicts_Hard_Disk_Failure)

Comment: Thank you, the part I don't understand though is what value I should look at to know the current status. Since 96/96/10 all are hardcoded values, how do I know how bad the problem is? Should I look at the raw value? Does it mean I have 10 (0A) reallocated sectors out of the threshold 10?

Comment: @this.lau_ The interpretation of the numbers depends on the disk manufacturer (and how they implemented smart on the disk). That's why I said in a comment on the question "Please edit and provide the full smart information and the make/model of the drive."

Comment: Your drive *could* fail at any moment or it could last a few more months it is impossible to tell. You should perform a backup now. Keep an eye on this value - if it keeps on increasing it means failure is imminent.